# React Native android: An absolute positioned, touchable element outside of the bounds of its parent is not clickable

Tags: android, css, react-native

I have a TouchableOpacity inside of a view. The view is small (height: 60) and the TouchableOpacity lies outside the bounds of its parent (position: absolute, top: 70). When the child is inside of the parent, i.e. top: 30, it's clickable, but when it's outside, it's not. And only the regions inside of the parent view are clickable (touch events pass through the regions out of bounds).
Does anyone know of a way to register TouchableOpacity clicks even when it's outside the bounds of its parent?

Note that this works on iOS. It seems to only be a bug on android.

```
<View style={{height: 60, width: '100%', zIndex: 1}}>
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => console.log('pressed')} style={{position: 'absolute', zIndex: 2, backgroundColor: 'yellow', width: 100, height: 50, top: 70}} />
</View>
```

Comment: have you tried setting `elevation:1`?  Android generally ignores `zIndex`

Comment: @MikeM Thanks for the suggestion! I just tried it, but still not working :/

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm having a similar problem

Comment: Same issue here as well.

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround so far is to

```
import { TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
```

Solution was found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/27232#issuecomment-819347427).